# Represent each student by vector in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes (df_names, df_topics), df_names containing the student name, topic preference of each student, and df_topics containing topics.

Here is a sample input dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_names = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'martin', 'jack'],
        'topics':['algebra; atom; evolution', 'chemical reaction; calculus; quantum',
                  'geometry; botany; electricity; mechanics',
                  'zoology; number theory; atom; evolution; calculus']})

df_topics= pd.DataFrame({'topics':['geometry','atom','evolution', 'calculus']})

k=df_topics['topics'].count()
```

[image]

[image]

I want to represent each student by k (here k=4) dimensional binary vector, i.e. if the student has a topic from df_topics, 1 is will be put in the corresponding position otherwise it will be 0.

results:

```
       geometry atom evolution calculus
                
tom     0       1      1       0
nick    0       0      0       1
martin  1       0      0       0
jack    0       1      1       1
```

Comment: Use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df = df_names[['Name']].join(df_names['topics'].str.get_dummies('; ')[df_topics['topics']])
print (df)
     Name  geometry  atom  evolution  calculus
0     Tom         0     1          1         0
1    nick         0     0          0         1
2  martin         1     0          0         0
3    jack         0     1          1         1
```

If need all categories:

```
df = df_names[['Name']].join(df_names['topics'].str.get_dummies('; '))
print (df)
     Name  algebra  atom  botany  calculus  chemical reaction  electricity  \
0     Tom        1     1       0         0                  0            0   
1    nick        0     0       0         1                  1            0   
2  martin        0     0       1         0                  0            1   
3    jack        0     1       0         1                  0            0   

   evolution  geometry  mechanics  number theory  quantum  zoology  
0          1         0          0              0        0        0  
1          0         0          0              0        1        0  
2          0         1          1              0        0        0  
3          1         0          0              1        0        1
```